# Cryptic clue let us.... [7]

Tags: cryptic-clues

Another cryptic clue:

> Let us hear the sound of solid structure [7]

hint 1

> While I was thinking about this clue my half drunk coffee went cold

Comment: You ... had the wrong enumeration?  That kinda makes a big difference hehe

Comment: @Rubio - yes........ I keep trying and I keep getting it wrong... many apoloiges...

Comment: @Rubio, but at least I had a better definition... an actual noun in there after the last one where you explained why I had it wrong :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confident the answer is.

> LATTICE. The def being solid structure. The wordplay being that "Let Us" sounds like Lattice. This also fits with the hint as "cold coffee"=latte+ice which sounds like lattice.

Comment: Yep - good job.. well done... -- read the clue out to yourself...

Comment: @tom oh. Duh. Got it.

Comment: Great job, well done - :-)....

Comment: nyfb unys qehax pbssr = ynggr yrff gur r (cneg qehax.) = yngg+ pbyq = vpr = ynggvpr.  (rot 13)

Comment: You folks pronounce things weird. Just sayin’. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Bridge -  a solid structure, and a part of the structure of a song.

Comment: I like the logic of your answer, but sorry not the answer I had in mind. +1 though. -- I will put hints up if not solved for a while...

Comment: So sorry : please see edit to this question - 7 letters not 6 - very very sorry....